# How do you find the transformation matrix from a CSS transform rotate(deg) rule?

Tags: javascript, html, css, math, geometry

Say I have a `div` that has a CSS rule of `transform: rotate(15deg)` applied. If I use JQuery to read the element's computed CSS transform, I see that the browser has converted the `rotate(15deg)` transform into a value of `matrix(0.965926, 0.258819, -0.258819, 0.965926, 0, 0)`.

I know the rotation value in degrees, and I'd like to calculate this rotation matrix without querying the DOM. How do I programmatically calculate an element's rotation matrix from the rotation in degrees?

Comment: It's more about Math: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transformation_matrix#Affine_transformations, and the 6 param represents the upper `2x3` from a `3x3` matrix.

Answer (score 3):

Ok, I've figured out the solution using [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25367782/1335679).

1. Convert the degree value to radians: `var radians = degrees * Math.PI / 180`.
2. Build the rotation matrix using this pattern: `matrix(a,b,c,d,e,f)`

   - `a = Math.cos(radians)`
   - `b = Math.sin(radians)`
   - `c = -b`
   - `d = a`
   - `e = 0`
   - `f = 0`

The computed CSS values in the browser are rounded to 6 decimal places, so in order to match that exactly you can add the additional step of:

```
a = parseFloat(a.toFixed(6))
```